Adjusting YouTube HTTP Request with Refresh Token for unlimited communication


#1 shows the google developers oauth center where I get my access token. I want to use that to change and modify descriptions and tags etc.
Now, it works perfectly (addressing the endpoint: googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos ) but the problem is that the token is active for only 1 hour (god knows why). But they provide a refresh Token.
So the question is how the refresh token can be embedded in the (image #2) Make.com HTTP Request some way or if there is a work around within another automation that automatically updates the token? I am not sure.
Tried to just add the refresh token to the header but didnt work.


So the question is how the refresh token can be embedded in the (image #2) Make.com HTTP Request some way or if there is a work around within another automation that automatically updates the token?

It can not.
In order to get a new refresh token you must exchange your refresh token for a new one.
This is done with a http post request
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=[redacted]&grant_type=refresh_token

So you would need to do this request first in order to get a new access token and then apply it to what ever that page is that you are using the access token.

Tried it and inserted the 3 values in ClientId, ClientSecret and redacted        and passed nothing in the header and body type and it returned a 404

It's a http post and that's the post body

Just checking did you send it to the token endpoint?

Yes but I tried to insert client ID etc. in the URL as well. So I have to pass these 4 values then client id client secret and refresh token and grant token?

Problem is I am not sure how to set up the call. You mentioned its part of the body but within a single HTTP request I can only add "name" and "value" in the header. Here is an image of the request I made returned a 400 error telling me   {
"error": "unsupported_grant_type",
"error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}                             https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e2C_ca9YhMxT95hOpSD3K277XoTgmUck/view?usp=drive_link
